# Troubleshooting a networking issue, on my Premise Router. Need to script python to help tshoot the issue

Tags: python, networking

Issue:

Since a SW upgrade on my router, once in a while it takes (random occurrence) 3-5 seconds to load a webpage (happens more often on pages that arent cached).

I am trying to run a python script to get the "webpage" load times for different websites.

Will this script provide me accurate webpage load times?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from time import time 
new_list = {'https://www.nba.com', 'https://www.nfl.com', 'https://www.instagram.com/', 'https://www.twitter.com', 'https://www.mlb.com'} 
for j in new_list:     
    print(j)      
    stream = urlopen(j)      
    start_time = time()      
    output = stream.read()      
    end_time = time()      
    stream.close()      
    print(end_time-start_time)
```

I can add different website to the list, to get their times, but does this provide me accurate "page" load times?

If not, what tool can I use in Python to script this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That code only reads the base page. Its common for a page to pull in dozens of other pages (see the ads on this page for instance). One option is to install `selenium` which will drive your web browser. I think that would give you better times.

Comment: Good idea. Let me give that a shot. Thanks